# Fitting two populations to measurements using GEKKO

Tags: python, curve-fitting, differential-equations, gekko

I need to fit the sum of two populations defined by two different partial equations depending onto 3 parameters to a list of measurements of type (mesurement, time) using GEKKO.
The differential equations are:

```
dS/dt = (a - b) * S
dR/dt = (a - b - c)* R
X(t) = S(t) + R(t)
```

(a,b,c are parameters)

I need to fit X to the measurements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are sample measured `X` values:

```py
# data
m.time = [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,1]
x_meas = [1.1,1.2,1.56,1.77,1.89,2.1,2.3,2.5,2.7,2.2,2.1]
```

Gekko adjusts the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```py
# parameters, single value over time horizon
p = m.Array(m.FV,3,lb=0.5,ub=10); a,b,c = p
# turn STATUS On for adjustment by solver
for fv in p:
   fv.STATUS=1
```

The value of `X` is calculated with differential equations for `S` and `R` and an algebraic equation with `X=S+R`.

```py
# variables
S,R,X = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=0)
# change initial conditions
S0,R0 = [0.35,0.65]; X0 = S0+R0
S.value=S0; R.value=R0; X.value=X0

# equations
m.Equations([S.dt()==(a-b)*S,
             R.dt()==(a-b-c)*R,
             X==S+R])
```

The squared error between the measured `X` values and the predicted `X` value is minimized.

```py
# minimize difference to measurements
m.Minimize((X-Xm)**2)
```

A few configuration parameters are needed to run in dynamic estimation mode (`IMODE=5`) and with 3 collocation nodes per time step (`NODES=3`).

```py
m.options.IMODE = 5   # dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 3   # collocation nodes
m.solve(disp=False)   # display solver output
```

This produces an optimized solution that minimizes the squared error, but is not unique because `a` and `b` are co-linear parameters. The solver can increase `a` and `b` and get the same answer.

[image: fit data]

Here is the complete script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# data
m.time = [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,1]
x_meas = [1.1,1.2,1.56,1.77,1.89,2.1,2.3,2.5,2.7,2.2,2.1]

# parameters, single value over time horizon
p = m.Array(m.FV,3,lb=0.5,ub=10); a,b,c = p
# turn STATUS On for adjustment by solver
for fv in p:
   fv.STATUS=1
   
# variables
S,R,X = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=0)
# change initial conditions
S0,R0 = [0.35,0.65]; X0 = S0+R0
S.value=S0; R.value=R0; X.value=X0 

# measured values
Xm = m.Param(x_meas)

# equations
m.Equations([S.dt()==(a-b)*S,
             R.dt()==(a-b-c)*R,
             X==S+R])

# minimize difference to measurements
m.Minimize((X-Xm)**2)

m.options.IMODE = 5   # dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 3   # collocation nodes
m.solve(disp=False)   # display solver output

print(f'a: {a.value[0]}, b: {b.value[0]}, c: {c.value[0]}')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))
plt.plot(m.time,S.value,'b:',linewidth=3,label='S')
plt.plot(m.time,R.value,'r--',linewidth=2,label='R')
plt.plot(m.time,X.value,'k--',label='X')
plt.plot(m.time,Xm.value,'kx',label='Xm')
plt.legend(); plt.grid(); plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('fit.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

Additional example problems are available from the [Dynamic Optimization course](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DynamicEstimation).

Comment: Thanks, just another question is there the possibility to manage the first values of S and R through another parameter.
Something like 
fraction_0 = ... # new parameter
S0,R0 = [fraction_0*x_means[0] , (1-fraction_0)*x_means[0]]; X0 = S0+R0
S.value=S0; R.value=R0; X.value=X0

Comment: Yes, that is also possible. If you have trouble configuring this, could you pose a new question with that specific request? You can make the initial conditions calculated with `fixed_initial=False` when specifying the variable.

Comment: Thanks, here is the new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78019439/fitting-two-populations-to-measurements-using-gekko-how-to-optimize-the-first-da